# How can you reliably unpack a Windows driver manually?

Tags: windows, unpacking, driver

When you unpack manually a Windows user-mode executable, you can easily break at its EntryPoint (or TLS), then trace until you reach the original EntryPoint. However that's not possible with a packed driver.

How can you reliably unpack a Windows driver manually?

Comment: Who doesn't miss the greatest of all of them, Softice

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I kind of like your answer about changing the subsystem, especially if you're not a fan of kernel debugging.  I'm a big fan of Windbg, though.  The way I do this is:

1. Hook up my kernel debugger to a VM
2. Change the first byte of the driver's entry point to be an INT3 (0xCC).
3. Fix-up the PE checksum (I'm a fan of letting [pefile](https://code.google.com/p/pefile/) do this work for me).
4. Load the driver in the VM ( [OSR](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=157) has a great driver loader )

The kernel should call `DriverEntry()` on your driver and break into your debugger for you.  Then you can trace the code until you find the OEP as you would have done anyway.  The main advantage I see to this method is that you don't have to fake kernel DLLs or calls that the driver might do during unpacking, and it works on x64.

Comment: You might hit the wall on newer Windows versions, though. The answer of the OP is more versatile in that sense, but yours is certainly more professional :) ... also don't forget `devcon` for the driver loading needs (comes with source in the DDKs/WDKs)

Comment: @0xC0000022L I haven't had a problem with this on newer versions of Windows; just do the normal stuff like enable test signing, etc.  Admittedly, I haven't tried it on Windows 8, though.  Did something change?

Comment: @mrduclaw how do i Change the first byte of the driver's entry point to be an INT3?!??

Comment: @AminM Sorry for the late response, I haven't checked this account in a long time.  Open the file in IDA, find the bytes of where the entry-point is.  Open it in a hex editor and chnage it to a 0xCC (break-point).  Or, you can probably edit it directly in IDA these days.  Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

1. change the driver subsystem to GUI (turning it into a user-mode binary)
2. clear the imports' RVA, or use a [set of fake kernel DLLs](http://corkami.googlecode.com/files/usermode_drivers2.zip) (only in 32 bits) to enable imports loading
3. launch in your debugger and proceed as if it was user-mode - you'll probably need to simulate some API calls before reaching the original EntryPoint.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to patching the DriverInit function with an INT3 is to put a breakpoint in the **IopLoadDriver** function which is responsible for calling DriverInit. On Windows XP SP3, the breakpoint should be added at **IopLoadDriver+0x66a** which is `call    dword ptr [edi+2Ch]` (0x2C is _DRIVER_OBJECT.DriverInit).

1. Find IopLoadDriver with `x nt!IopLoadDriver`
2. Add a breakpoint at IopLoadDriver+0x66a
3. Load and start your driver

Offsets for other Windows versions:

- Windows 7 Pro SP1 32-bit German: nt!IopLoadDriver+0x7eb
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit US: nt!IopLoadDriver+0xA04
- Windows 10 Pro x64 US: nt!IopLoadDriver+0x51C (Build 10586.420)

(If you have offsets for other versions of Windows, please edit this answer)

Comment: Nice bit of info. It is always valuable to have bits and pieces which you can put together as reverser. Also remember you can get a good guess of the implementation details in Windows by looking at the ReactOS source code.

Answer (score 6):

`nt!IopLoadDriver` indirect call is used only for SERVICE_DEMAND start driver entry

for boot loading drivers you would need to break on `nt!IopInitializeBuiltInDriver` indirect call as well

you can see a short example on message #17 & #18 in this link

http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=231280

this is a dormant script (slightly edited to use gc (go from conditional instead of go as recommended ) that keeps waiting forever and will print out the !drvobj details
when ever any driver is loaded in a kernel debugging session

no word wraps the command should be in a single line

```
.foreach /pS 1 /ps 10 ( place { # call*dword*ptr*\[*\+*\] nt!IopInitializeBuiltinDriver} ) {bu place ".printf  \"%msu\\n\", poi(esp+4);r $t0 = poi(esp); gu; !drvobj $t0 2;gc"}
.foreach /pS 1 /ps 10 ( place { # call*dword*ptr*\[*\+*\] nt!IoploadDriver} ) {bu place ".printf  \"%msu\\n\", poi(esp+4);r $t1 = poi(esp); gu; !drvobj $t1 2;gc"}
```

xp sp3 vm

in a connected kd session 
do `sxe ibp; .reboot` 
kd will request an initial break on rebooting (equivalent to /break switch in boot.ini)
when broken 
run this script

```
$$>a< "thisscript.extension"
```

in addition to printing all the system driver entry points and their driver objects

if your application loads an additional driver their details will be printed too

a sample output for sysinternals dbgview opened in the target vm

the dbgv.sys entry point is called when you `check mark the enable kernel capture  (ctrl+k)`

```
\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\DBGV
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Dbgv.sys
Driver object (ffbd6248) is for:
 \Driver\DBGV
DriverEntry:   f6d89185 Dbgv
DriverStartIo: 00000000 
DriverUnload:  00000000 
AddDevice:     00000000 

Dispatch routines:
[00] IRP_MJ_CREATE                      f6d87168    Dbgv+0x1168
[01] IRP_MJ_CREATE_NAMED_PIPE           804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[02] IRP_MJ_CLOSE                       f6d87168    Dbgv+0x1168
[03] IRP_MJ_READ                        804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[04] IRP_MJ_WRITE                       804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[05] IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION           804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[06] IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION             804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[07] IRP_MJ_QUERY_EA                    804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[08] IRP_MJ_SET_EA                      804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[09] IRP_MJ_FLUSH_BUFFERS               804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0a] IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION    804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0b] IRP_MJ_SET_VOLUME_INFORMATION      804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0c] IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL           804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0d] IRP_MJ_FILE_SYSTEM_CONTROL         804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[0e] IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL              f6d87168    Dbgv+0x1168
[0f] IRP_MJ_INTERNAL_DEVICE_CONTROL     804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[10] IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN                    804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[11] IRP_MJ_LOCK_CONTROL                804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[12] IRP_MJ_CLEANUP                     804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[13] IRP_MJ_CREATE_MAILSLOT             804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[14] IRP_MJ_QUERY_SECURITY              804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[15] IRP_MJ_SET_SECURITY                804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[16] IRP_MJ_POWER                       804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[17] IRP_MJ_SYSTEM_CONTROL              804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[18] IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CHANGE               804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[19] IRP_MJ_QUERY_QUOTA                 804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[1a] IRP_MJ_SET_QUOTA                   804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
[1b] IRP_MJ_PNP                         804fa87e    nt!IopInvalidDeviceRequest
```