# Is there an easier way to break on a rootkit driver load, other than disassembling IopLoadDriver?

Tags: malware, windbg, kernel

The only method i know to break on a `DriverEntry` of a rootkit driver when its loaded is to disassmble `nt!IopLoadDriver` and find an indirect call in it and break on it. Setting a break point on `rootkitDriverName!DriverEntry` doesn't work either for some reason.

Is there any easier way to break on the rootkit driver entry? Why does `rootkitDriverName!DriverEntry` not work?

Comment: Here are more info about this, and nicely explained few different methods https://blogg.pwc.no/styringogkontroll/starting-dynamic-analysis-on-a-windows-x64-rootkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enabling break on module load:

```
sxe ld rootkitDriverName
```

See also https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2638/60

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, this still doesnt break on the driverEntry of the rootkit driver and instead its in a kernel function related to debugging, and using bu rootkitDriver!DriverEntry doesnt work, it gives this error "Couldn't resolve error". (I am loading the driver using OSRloader)

Comment: with sxe ld you also need !gflag +ksl and a valid pdb and /or .reload /f  (couldnt resolve is because you do not have a symbol file )

Comment: @Notoriouss: I think `!drvobj` should display the entry address so you can set breakpoint there.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky but !drvobj gives the symbol error as well, i do not have the pdb file for the driver tho, should the symbol get resolved considering i don't have the pdb?  i use !drvobj rootkitdrivername, the same name that i registered with OSRloader, and the same one that lm shows

Comment: @Notoriouss are you sure the error is about the driver and not kernel symbols which are necessary for the command to work?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky yes its for the driver, and i also did the .reload /f to make sure all the symbols are loaded, still i cannot use the rootkit's driver name to break

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Are you sure this works when we don't have the symbols for the driver? considering OP is asking about rootkits i doubt there is any symbol available.